# How do I defeat the guy in the armor in Stuck on Crushing?

Tags: uncharted-3

I'm in chapter 14 Stuck on Crushing in *Uncharted 3* and I have to defeat this guy in an armor while we're on a boat.

[image]

It doesn't matter how I try to hit him, nothing seems to hurt him: headshots, shooting while he's throwing a grenade, throwing grenades at him. When you get close enough to fight him, he simply kicks you away so that's no good either.

So how do I defeat this guy?

Comment: Sounds like a puzzle boss!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Evade him for awhile and fight some of the other men who jump down eventually. Most of them are easy one shot kills with any gun just to occupy your time. Keep running from the big man until a goon with a grenade launcher shows up just above the red door. Kill him and the grenade launcher will fall to the ground intentionally for you. Use it on the big man, 3 or 4 shots will kill him.  If you loose the launcher, (as I did) then just kill gooneys until you have four grenades.  Keep chucking grenades until he has no armor, then use a kal 7 to finish him off.

Comment: When the guy drops the grenade launcher, just get it and get to cover ASAP. Picking up the launcher triggers more goons dropping in, basically behind you. I'd recommend vaulting over the cargo containers to get as far from the red door as possible, before using it. This should get you breathing room to turn and land a couple of well aimed shots on the Big Goon.

Comment: I'd further add that I had far better luck dealing with the lesser goons by simple run-and-gun than in trying to pick them off with aimed shots.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is by where he jumps down there should be a big yellow crate. Jump on and go all the way to the right. Doing that makes it easier to hit him and gives you cover he can't flank.

Answer (score 0):

Just run around and dodge kill the little guys run around then kill the guys with the Hammer the Hammer will fall down and all you have to do is shoot him about 3 times something like that but it depends and then you have to kill more little guys

Answer (score 0):

I got stuck on this for ages and did it by luck after a long fight, but I had to restart the chapter and I found that picking up the pistole from the first enemy you encounter and picking up the grenades from the second is enough to kill him! As soon as he jumps off, throw your two grenades at him, then shoot him with the pistole a few times and then he dies, i managed to do it straight away doing this